# How to print a first line having a specific string after last occurrence of another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named **file.txt**

`file.txt`

```
this is first line
this is second line 
new( line added )
this is second line
this is fourth line
new( line three added)
this is fourth line_1
this is fifth line_three
this is fourth line_1
this is fourth line_5
```

from this file i need to print line That have string `"fourth"` after the last occurrence of string `"new("`

**Expected output:**

`this is fourth line_1`

This is current attempt:

```
fin = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in reversed(fin.readlines()):
    if 'new(' in line:
```

this will go to last line that have string new( in it. Now i need to check the first occurrence of string `fourth` after that last `new(` and print that line. How can i do this?

Comment: When your statement `if 'new(' in line:` is `True`, then it means you have `new(` in your current line. Thus, when printing `line`, you'll obviously get a string that have `new(` in it. So this behavior is normal. That being said, I have to admit I haven't understood what your objective was, nor what was the problem...

Comment: Sorry for not stating my objective clearly. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read 2 lines at once and check 2 conditions at once.

```
lines = open('file.txt').readlines()
for item, next_item in zip(lines, lines[1:]):

    if 'new(' in item and 'fourth' in  next_item:

        print(next_item)
```

Gives #

```
this is fourth line_1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with

```py
from typing import Optional

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

line_new_index: Optional[int] = None
line_fourth_index: Optional[int] = None

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "new(" in line:
        line_new_index = index
        line_fourth_index = None
    if "fourth" in line and line_new_index is not None and line_fourth_index is None:
        line_fourth_index = index

print(lines[line_fourth_index])
```

This effectively prints `this is fourth line_1` with the file you provided